# Viewbag not working on IIS 6 server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone got a clue why the ViewBag does not work in my MVC 3 application when deployed to an IIS6 server ? Everything else works fine. It does not even result in an error of some kind, it's just empty...

We're using an old server2003 server for internal test purposes sometimes and it would be nice to get it to work :).

EDIT: The code is working fine on my devmachine and on another IIS 7 server.

EDIT II: A recompilation and redeployment fixed it. Very odd.

Comment: No clue, it should work. Can you show us some code? Did you try running the default project created with VS2010 template?

Comment: Server 2003 is not the problem.  (I'm using ViewBag on Server 2003 with IIS  myself without issue.)

Comment: Ok then I must have missed a setting of some kind ...

Answer (score 0):

Since ViewBag is a dynamic. The property does not have intellisense, just don't forget the dynamic property is case sensitive if you use c#.

Comment: The thing is, is that it's working fine on another server and on my dev machine. Maybe I wasn't clear enough.